# Generate unique ID across multiple independent servers

Tags: java, server, uniqueidentifier

I have a system that has 4 servers and each server has its own .war file that hosts on it. Each time the user make calls for a particular function the server should generate a unique id. At a given point there may be hundreds of active instances from all the four servers.

Is there any way to generate id in each server that is totally unique and not generated by the other server?

Comment: `UUID.randomUUID.toString()` should be safe I am guessing

Comment: Yes, I would also use UUID. The chance to genearte twice the same is on 1 in 17Billion. Otherwise use UUID and the current date in millis. You also can add your hostname to the id, to be safe the id is not generated by other servers

Comment: you can use hardware id/address (MAC Address) + time in millis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the [UUID](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/UUID.html). This is an defined format for these universal identifiers. I used it when I had multiple Servers.  Or you use a combination of time, a random number and some system-specific data like IP, MAC...